# Subsequent EF migrations fail on database-update: Table already exists

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

I am able to successfully create a migration with `Add-Migration InitialMigration`, and apply it with `update-database`, per the [Microsoft doco](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=vs).

Making changes to my model, I add a second migration `Add-Migration UpdatedModel`, and this works. However, it is not a cumulative change - it is just like the initial migration, with the `Up` method containing `CreateTable` statements.

As a result, the `update-database` command fails on that second and subsequent attempts, complaining that the tables already exist.

Am I expecting too much from EF or does this seem like an issue? It seems that the point of the migrations is to manage cumulative updates.

The obvious workaround is to drop the database, and/or delete all migration files, so that subsequent migrations are always the initial one. This will get messy as I start to get some data beyond seed data into the test database.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the model you have. Provide a [mcve], which shows the error message you get.

Comment: Yes, migrations should be incremental - not cumulative. It does this by doing a model compare from the prior migration. Any chance you wiped the __MigrationHistory table or re-created the database?

Comment: @SteveGreene I posted an answer if you are interested to know. I appreciate you verifying that there was indeed something wrong.

Comment: You could also have asked @SteveGreene to post an answer, and Accepted that one

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that the `Migrations/AssetContextModelSnapshot.cs` file got generated with the initial migration, however, it was not included in the project. Therefore, the project did not have the history of migrations available to it, and each migration was new. Right-click -> Include in project + save all, and problem solved!